# Magnific Popup : Scroll icon doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a website, and I've used magnific popup just to make my images in a section be zoomed in.
I can click on every images and it works.The problem is that scroll icon that helps to view other images doesn't appear.

Here you can find a part of concerned htl page with js code:

```
<div class="row no-bord">
    <div class="col-md-3 pic">
        <div class="img-seletion">
            <a href="img/work_section/coaching-coders-coding-7374.jpg" title="pic1">
                <img src="img/work_section/coaching-coders-coding-7374.jpg" alt="pic1" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 pic">
        <div class="img-seletion">
            <a href="img/work_section/adult-business-coding-1181677.jpg" title="pic2">
                <img src="img/work_section/adult-business-coding-1181677.jpg" alt="pic1" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js code:

```
$(function(){
    $(".no-bord").magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a', type: 'image'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<div class="row no-bord">
    <div class="col-md-3 pic">
        <div class="img-seletion">
            <a href="img/work_section/coaching-coders-coding-7374.jpg" title="pic1" class='popup'>
                <img src="img/work_section/coaching-coders-coding-7374.jpg" alt="pic1" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 pic">
        <div class="img-seletion">
            <a href="img/work_section/adult-business-coding-1181677.jpg" title="pic2" class='popup'>
                <img src="img/work_section/adult-business-coding-1181677.jpg" alt="pic1" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$(function(){
    $(".popup").magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a', type: 'image'
    });
});
```

let me know if it does't work.

Comment: I tried your method but unfortunately it doesn't work.The images are zommed well but the scroll icon still unshown.

Comment: please check if you have correctly included the required css file. i mean magnific-popup.css file

Comment: I checked it's all defined,

Comment: add this css
.popup{
cursor:zoom-in;
}

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
.popup{
    cursor:zoom-in;
}
```